# How to define implementation of function call signatures and construct signatures in typescript

Tags: typescript

The typescript documentation talks about function `call signatures` and `construct signatures` and describes how you can declare the type and use it. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#call-signatures

**call signatures** (with no implemetation of a function with type `DescribableFunction`)

```
type DescribableFunction = {
  description: string;
  (someArg: number): boolean;
};
function doSomething(fn: DescribableFunction) {
  console.log(fn.description + " returned " + fn(6));
}
```

**construct signatures**(with no implementation of a function with type `SomeConstructor`)

```
type SomeConstructor = {
  new (s: string): SomeObject;
};
function fn(ctor: SomeConstructor) {
  return new ctor("hello");
}
```

But it never shows how to define the actual implementation of such functions. And I searched a lot for days, but can't seem to find anything on it. A simple example of each with how to use it and when you would use it would be very helpful in understanding these concepts.

I tried to do it like this of `call signatures` but obviously its throwing error

```
type DescribableFunction = {
  description: string;
  (str: string): string;
}

const df: DescribableFunction = {
  description: 'df function description',
  (str: string): {
    return str;
  }
}

console.log(df.description, df('hello world'));
```

[ts playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&noUnusedLocals=true&noUnusedParameters=true&target=5&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&noFallthroughCasesInSwitch=true&noImplicitOverride=true&noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature=true&allowUnusedLabels=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAIhDOBjATgSwEYEN0BsIDEBXAO0WFQHtioBeKAbwFgAoKKAEwRVTHKoC4o8YGmIBzANws2ACmHJB81OICUikcsksAvixaIqwjgDNBcJGiy4CJMpWp0mrDlzS97ggOTtjUY7b5qTgseQM8AGmkoORF1UTE1Bii2ZAhgQmRqeSlnXWY8-UMKPAA6HAoxGR8S4O53KnCTGU8ACwgccqgAdwpkHHZPFRUJIA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "literal" syntax for declaring a function with extra properties.
But functions are normal objects, and properties can be added to them:

```
const df: DescribableFunction = (str: string) => {
  return str;
}
df.description = "df function description"
```

Typically, Typescript would complain that property `description` is missing in the initial declartion of `df`, but it looks like it makes an exception for functions, allowing them to be added later on.

As for *constructor signatures*, they map nicely to the *class syntax*. Take the following example:

```
type CacheableConstructor = {
  new(s: string): { x: number };
  cached: boolean
};
```

It can be implemented like this:

```
class SomeCC {
  static cached = false
  x: number
  constructor(s: string) {}
}

// check that if matches the constructor signaure
const cc: CacheableConstructor = SomeCC
```

Comment: Thanks for the ans. I actually tried this approach but would stop after defining the function and typescript throwing an error, but as you said, it seems even if we define it afterwards sepearately, ts picks up on it and reverts the error.<br>As I asked in my question, are there any special cases where call and construct signatures are actually useful?! Expecially in the construct signatures case, aren't interface the "recommended" way to define class types?

Comment: The *call signature* is only useful to describe extra properties on a function, which is relatively uncommon. The *constructor signature* however allows you to define static properties as well as the signature of the constructor of a class. Those are not really meant to be "implemented" like in your question, but serve as types in e.g function arguments. Interfaces serve as a "blueprint" for (the instance of) a class.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, `Object.assign` has a signature that returns an interection type of its arguments

```
Object.assign<T,U>( t: T, u: U ) : T & U
```

it could be then just

```
type DescribableFunction = {
  description: string;
  (str: string): string;
}

const df: DescribableFunction = Object.assign( 
    (str: string) => str,
    { description: 'df function description' },
);

console.log(df.description, df('hello world'));
// works
```

This has a drawback, it only works when you assign the description to the function and not the other way around, although TypeScript types both.

```
// types correctly but doesn't work (for obvious reason)
type DescribableFunction = {
  description: string;
  (str: string): string;
}

const df: DescribableFunction = Object.assign( 
    { description: 'df function description' },
    (str: string) => str,
);

console.log(df.description, df('hello world'));
// df is not a function
```

Answer (score 1):

I did not know this myself, but the compiler will actually check that you set the `description` property after creating the function:

```
type DescribableFunction = {
  description: string;
  (str: string): string;
}

const df: DescribableFunction = (str: string) => {
  return str;
}

// if you comment out the following line, the compiler will complain
df.description = 'df function description',

console.log(df.description, df('hello world'));
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&allowUnusedLabels=true&noUnusedLocals=true&noUnusedParameters=true&target=5&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&noFallthroughCasesInSwitch=true&noImplicitOverride=true&noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature=true#code/LAKALgngDgpgBAERgZwMYCcCWAjAhtgGxgDEBXAO1TEwHty4BeOAb1DjgBMUNMpq6AXHGRgs5AOYBuNnAAUI9EIWYJASiWiVU0AF9QoVHRGcAZkKRoseQiQpVa9JvNEax41YwB8LGehhhSdHoFaRA9EFAAeki4TBM4CBpSOEMAW1SYcjA4JOywAAt4ExoCAhoAdy04AhUYABo4Avg0qEwidDhK0pSaVKgCXBVQDhMAOi5LXn5HOAByEbgTO2nObiw+B1m6-RBDcmQSmFGy8VkR8bWphwaR2VnC0ppOmnQCDlnVVVCgA)

Answer (score -1):

I think I found the answer for your question. we should use `const` when we declare `df` instead of `var` or `let`. if you declare it using `var` or `let`  typescript will throw an error

*
"Property 'description' is missing in type '(str: string) => string' but required in type 'DescribableFunction'.ts(2741) test.ts(2, 5): 'description' is declared here."
*