# Declare callable function with method properties

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to declare a type that is self-callable and can have functions too?

For example:

```
hello('Lucy') //self calling
hello.hi('John') //method inside)
hello.bye('Marie') //
```

How can Hello be made self-callable and have methods too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by declaring an object with a [call signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#call-signatures):

```typescript
interface Hello {
  (name: string): void;
  hi(name: string): void;
  bye(name: string): void;
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgBIQDYYPbIN4CwAUMsgBQhwC2EAXMgM5hSgDmAlPQG7bAAmAbmKkAFsArU6jZm07Ie-ISWQAjAJ4QJNekxYgO3XoOIBfYsT4QEGOFBQJsIJshGYc9dFmxLirr2QByABkAVwQ1APZfN2wAOjFAgClsERBI6K9Y9U0AgFlbYAhIoA)

or

```typescript
interface Hello {
  (name: string): void;
  hi: (name: string) => void;
  bye: (name: string) => void;
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgBIQDYYPbIN4CwAUMsgBQhwC2EAXMgM5hSgDmAlPQG7bAAmAbmKkAFsHoVqdRszbtkAXgB8yHvyElkAIwCe0yTXpMWIDopVrBxAL7FifCAgxwoKBNhBNkIzDnrosbA1iH0CyAHIAGQBXBB1w9hDfbAA6MQiAKWwREASkwJTdCAiAWRdgCASgA)

These describes an object that can be called with a string and two callable properties `hi` and `bye` both of which take a string as a parameter.

In the first case, they are described as methods, in the second as functions assigned to properties. [There is a small difference when it comes to variance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71600422/difference-between-functionname-void-and-functionnamevoid-in-an-interfa), however in a lot of cases it may not matter.

Comment: Can you please extend your example with simple console.log implementation for the 3 versions. Currently in your playground it does nothing.

Comment: @helloworld see [How to define implementation of function call signatures and construct signatures in typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69195747). I'd personally use Object.assign, but there are multiple ways to define these. Even just creating a function and assigning the properties in it. https://tsplay.dev/wEp8kW

Answer (score -1):

You can use a [Call Signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#call-signatures) to define a `type Hello` as follows:

```
type Hello = {
  (name: string): void;
  hi(name: string): void;
  bye(name: string): void;
};
```